How to export and import a fine-tuned AI model to a different instance of Azure AI Service or Azure OpenAI?
I post here because Microsoft Q&A Azure when I post my question I get the 404 code error.
Let's imagine that I am working with different environments for Development, Test, and Production, each having its own resource group with AI resources, Azure OpenAI Service, or Azure AI Services.
Now, after fine-tuning a model by AI engineers, I want to deploy it to a target instance that is different from the source/training instance.
However, I cannot choose the target instance as the option is grayed out, here in Azure AI Studio.

Here are my connected services:

In AzureOpenAI studio:

The target instance, whatever in the same or different region, is referenced by connection in Azure AI studio.

Is it possible to deploy to a target instance that is different from the source instance?\

Can it be automated by CI/CD pipelines?

Where can I find documentation about this classic scenario?


By the way, for Azure Synapse Workspace, it is possible to generate an artifact/Synapse ARM JSON template and deploy it to various environments/instances.
Thanks for helping me out.
I tried multiple instance of hub and project for Azure AI Studio and also Azure OpenAI Studio but there is no option to deploy to other instance of service,

According to this documentation
you deploy the fine-tuned model to different to a different subscription/region.
And below is the sample python code
import json
import os
import requests

token= os.getenv("<TOKEN>") 

subscription = "<DESTINATION_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>"  
resource_group = "<DESTINATION_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>"
resource_name = "<DESTINATION_AZURE_OPENAI_RESOURCE_NAME>"

source_subscription = "<SOURCE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>"
source_resource_group = "<SOURCE_RESOURCE_GROUP>"
source_resource = "<SOURCE_RESOURCE>"


source = f'/subscriptions/{source_subscription}/resourceGroups/{source_resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/{source_resource}'

model_deployment_name ="gpt-35-turbo-ft" # custom deployment name that you will use to reference the model when making inference calls.

deploy_params = {'api-version': "2023-05-01"} 
deploy_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token), 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}



deploy_data = {
    "sku": {"name": "standard", "capacity": 1}, 
    "properties": {
        "model": {
            "format": "OpenAI",
            "name": <"FINE_TUNED_MODEL_NAME">, # This value will look like gpt-35-turbo-0613.ft-0ab3f80e4f2242929258fff45b56a9ce 
            "version": "1",
            "source": source
        }
    }
}
deploy_data = json.dumps(deploy_data)

request_url = f'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription}/resourceGroups/{resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/{resource_name}/deployments/{model_deployment_name}'

print('Creating a new deployment...')

r = requests.put(request_url, params=deploy_params, headers=deploy_headers, data=deploy_data)

print(r)
print(r.reason)
print(r.json())

and the same you can use it in you CI/CD pipelines.
For more information regarding fine-tuned model deployment go through this documentation.
You also mentioned

However, I cannot choose the target instance as the option is grayed out (in Azure AI Studio).

That is because the target region is not supported for deployment.
Below is the limitation for cross region/subscription deployment.

The only limitations are that the new region must also support fine-tuning and when deploying cross subscription the account generating the authorization token for the deployment must have access to both the source and destination subscriptions.


What do you mean by the "target region is not supported for deployment"? When I want to use the new instance of service in the same region, I still cannot deploy the model using Azure AI Studio.

Ok in the same region and same subscription you created new ai resource and trying to deploy there. Try above code  once providing with the same source and destination except resource name. Also please add the screen shot where you are facing blockers.

I was talking about the UI interface.
But I used your code, and I was able to deploy to a new instance of Azure OpenAI within the same regions.
BTW, I was trying to do the same with the fine-tuned model created within Azure AI Studio in the AI Services that integrates Azure OpenAI and it is not possible (I checked the paths for resources / providers and they are the same):
<Response [400]>
Bad Request
{'error': {'code': 'BadRequest', 'message': 'Currently only OpenAI is supported, given kind is AIServices.'}}

Can you add the screen shot of the error in the question

I will try to put it in the original question when edit queue would allow me.

I managed to add the screenshots

The error says you are using AIservice type for deployment. Give Azure opensi kind

Also why are asking to use this in ci/cd when you want in UI?  Use sdks.

Is both of your azure openai resources in correct region for deployment?

Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/models#fine-tuning-models

Also why are asking to use this in ci/cd when you want in UI? Use sdks =>
I wanted first to try it by using UI 5if it is in Azure Portal then it can be done by code), I forgot that first features are coming to REST API and then in Azure CLI / Az PowerShell.

The error says you are using AIservice type for deployment. Give Azure opensi kind  =>
I changed the value of format in the JSON body form OpenAI to AI AIServices but this do not have any effect

Is both of your azure openai resources in the correct region for deployment? => yes, and I checked the documentation.
By using the REST API it is working (for Azure OpenAI), the studio does not propose the choice

The error says you need to use azure openai for cross region/subscription deployment and not the ai studio. since it currently doesn't support.
